# Get the computer name

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to get the current computer name.

this is my code:

```
Public Function GetComputerName() As String
    Dim ComputerName As String
    ComputerName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
    Return ComputerName
End Function
```

this code working, but i remember that there is faster way.

what is the fast way to get the computer name?

Comment: Just use this line of Code `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName` and remove the function or this `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

you can just use without function:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
```

or:

```
Environment.MachineName
```

Comment: thnk you, This is exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 7):

This is not that good the previous anwser,but if you love to work with forms:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Text = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName

End Sub
```

System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation gives a lot of nice informations.

-> UserDomainName

-> UserName

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice static property that should work anywhere in your program and in both VB.NET and C#:

```
System.Environment.MachineName
```

Because **System** namespace is imported automatically by default, it should be enough to refer to it simply by typing **Environment.MachineName**.

For unknown reason **My.Computer.Name** is not working for many people (including me) despite it is often being mentioned as a correct way to get the current hostname. So you don't need to bother trying to make it work.

Comment: I do think by now you should have know what is the reason why you cant access "MY" in C#, but if you have not, then let me tell you this. C# does not supper "MY" Namespace.

Answer (score 3):

An other way to get the computer name not mentioned in the previous responses:

```
My.Computer.Name
```

**Edit**

Works for VB.NET only, not C#

Comment: I don't know why, but despite this answer is all over forums, it doesn't wotk for me. "My" namespace doesn't even contain Computer property. I don't have time to research why is that. Environment.MachineName solved problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For WPF application:

1. Place a Button and TextBlock on the MainWindow.xaml form
2. Create a name for the button and textblock. Example: TextBlock1,
   Button1

Code Example #1

```
Private Sub load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)Handles MyBase.Loaded

TextBlock1.Text = Environment.MachineName 

End Sub
```

Code Example #2

```
Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

TextBlock1.Text = Environment.MachineName 

MyBase.Title = "Hello " + Environment.MachineName 

End Sub
```

Hope this gives you a more understanding on how to show the users Computer Name.

I stopped using Windows Form Applications because they are way to laggy. Now I'm using WPF Applications mainly because its a lot smoother and it has more customizations and coding WPF applications are a lot similar to Windows Form Applications.