# “Computer is not a member of My” Error in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I try to run the following command:

```
 Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.Name)
```

I faced the following error:

> "Computer" is not a member of "programName.My"

I am sincerely asking to know how I can overcome this error

Comment: Looks like you defined your own identifier named "My".

Comment: I believe your question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388164/get-the-computer-name

Comment: No, actually I want to access all features of "My." like "My.Computer", "My. Application", "My.Settings" and so on.

Comment: As Hans says, looks like you made your own namespace called My (via `programName.My`) and your code is trying to read `Computer` from that namespace instead of the Microsoft-defined one. You need to tell the code exactly which namespace to look in

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(New Devices.ServerComputer().Name)`... As already mentioned you must have defined something already named `My` and it's conflicting with the framework namespace already.

Comment: You probably selected a .Net Core template to create the project.  The _My Namespace_ is a work in progress on the Core framework with minimal features currently supported.  See [Visual Basic in .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-in-net-core-3-0/) for some info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use without function:

> System.Net.Dns.GetHostName

or:

> Environment.MachineName

Comment: Thanks, it perfectly works for the computer's name. how can I get to other related information like clipboard and so on? These functions were available in the previous version of VB .NET under "My.Computer.Name" or "My.Computer.Info" and so on.